# Bulk export of binary waveform data from oscilloscope to data points (csv preferred)

Tags: csv, waveform, oscilloscope

I'm working with some binary waveform files from various early to mid-90's HP scopes. I am trying to do a bulk conversion (we have over 5000) of the files to CSV's and then upload them into a database. I've tried hexdump, xxd, od, strings, etc. and none of them seem to work. I did hunt down a programmers manual but it's not making a whole lot of sense.

The files have a preamble line as ascii text but then the data points are in binary and for some reason nothing I try can decode them. The preamble gives the data necessary to use the binary values and calculate the correct values. It also states that the data is in WORD format.

```
:WAV:PRE 2,1,32768,1,+4.000000E-08,-4.9722700001108E-06,0,+2.460630E-04,+2.500000E+00,16384;:WAV:DATA #800065536^W�^W�^W�^
```

I'm pretty confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

http://www.naic.edu/~phil/hardware/oscilloscopes/9000A_Programmer_Reference.pdf

specifically page 1-21. After `":WAV:DATA"`, I think the rest of the chunk above will have `65536 8-bit data bytes` (the start of which is represented above by �) . The `^W` is probably a delimiter, so you would have to parse that out. Just a thought.

UPDATE: I'm new to oscilloscope data collection and am trying to figure the whole thing out from scratch. So, on further digging, it looks like the data you have provided shows this:

PREamble:
 - WORD format (16-bit signed integers split into 2 8-bit bytes)
 - If there is a WAV:BYT section, that would specify byte order for each pair
 - RAW data
 - 32768 data points
 - COUNT = 1 (I'm not clear on the meaning of this)
 - Next 3 should be X increment, origin, reference
 - Next 3 should be Y increment, origin, reference, although the manual that I pointed you at above has many more fields than just these, so you might want to consult your specific scope manual.

DATA:
 - On closer examination, I don't think the ^W is a delimiter, I think it is the first byte of the pair (0010111). The � character is apparently a standard "I don't know how to represent this character" web representation. You would need to look at that character as 8 bits also.
 - 65536 byte pairs of data

I'm not finding a utility that will do this for you. I think you're going to have to write or acquire some code (Perl, C, Java, Python, VB, etc.) to get this done.